# GetSecretValue, get identity: get credentials: failed to refresh cached credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-rds, aws-secrets-manager

I have a basic Go code like this. Gives me the error:

```
2024/02/21 21:49:15 operation error Secrets Manager: GetSecretValue,
  get identity: get credentials: failed to refresh cached credentials,
  no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata,
  request canceled, context deadline exceeded
```

I've used amazon secret manager for aws-rds, and I'm sure credentials are right

```
secretName := "key"
region := "eu-central-1"

config, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithRegion(region))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Create Secrets Manager client
svc := secretsmanager.NewFromConfig(config)

input := &secretsmanager.GetSecretValueInput{
    SecretId:     aws.String(secretName),
    VersionStage: aws.String("AWSCURRENT"), 
}

result, err := svc.GetSecretValue(context.TODO(), input)
if err != nil {
    // For a list of exceptions thrown, see
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
    log.Fatal(err.Error())
}

// Decrypts secret using the associated KMS key.
var secretMap map[string]string
json.Unmarshal([]byte(*result.SecretString), &secretMap)

return secretMap
```

Comment: The error "no EC2 IMDS role found" makes me think that you are running this code on an EC2 instance, and that the instance is missing this IMDS role ...

Comment: I am trying to run on my local

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue right now.  If I figure it out, I'll pop an answer in for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you don't have AWS credentials saved on your local machine/environment. To do that follow any of these steps: https://wellarchitectedlabs.com/common/documentation/aws_credentials/ and just simply run the code again. I suggest using the CLI option as that worked easily for me.